# Image caching issue: Expires header resets on each revisit

Tags: node.js, image, nginx, caching, cache-control

I am encountering an issue with image caching on my website where the Expires header seems to be reset every time I revisit the site after closing the browser. The images are served by Nginx, and I have set the Cache-Control header to "public" with an appropriate max-age value. Despite these settings, the browser continues to download the images on each visit.

NGINX Configuration:

```
location ~ ^/images/(Folder1|Folder2|Folder3|Folder4|Folder5|Folder6|Folder7|Folder8|Folder9|Folder10)/ {
    root /var/www/app-folder/app/build;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header vary Accept-Encoding;
    expires 3h;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

Node.js Configuration:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './app/build')));
```

When I check the response headers from network tab, I can see:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=10800, public
Content-Length: 664057
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Date: Sat, 11 Nov 2023 17:42:08 GMT
Expires: Sat, 11 Nov 2023 20:42:08 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 17 May 2023 02:38:37 GMT
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
```

Observations:

The Expires date in response header appears to reset on each new visit and the image is downloaded again. If I am browsing in the same session, only then the images are retrieved from disk cache. Is this the expected behavior? Shouldn't the images stay cached and revalidate every 3 hours?

The server is running Nginx version 1.18.0 on Ubuntu.

I would appreciate any insights into why the Expires header is being reset on each new visit and how to ensure that images are retrieved from the cache as expected. Are there any additional troubleshooting steps I should take or configurations I should check?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The `Expires` header isn't relevant since you've included a `max-age`. These header values seem fine and you should indeed expect the resource to be retrieved from the cache for 3 hours. The most common issue in cases like this is that the cache is actually disabled (common when using developer tools) or you're misinterpreting cache hits as misses.